# YouTube - MP4 to MP3 messes up

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

It's supposed to download all the videos in the playlist and convert them to mp3. But all this does is make the mp4's and 1 empty mp3 with a number higher than the max mp4. My newbie brain doesn't know how to fix this...

```
var ytpl = require('ytpl');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var binaries = require('ffmpeg-static');
var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

var output_dir = path.join(__dirname+"/dl");

ytpl("PL8n8S4mVUWvprlN2dCAMoIo6h47ZwR_gn", (err, pl) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    let c = 0;

    pl.items.forEach((i) => {
        ytdl(i.url_simple+"", { filter: 'audioonly' }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output_dir+"/"+c+".mp4")).on('finish', () => {
            console.log("Finished MP4 DL, starting conversion...");
            ffmpeg(output_dir+"/"+c+".mp4")
                .setFfmpegPath(binaries.path)
                .format('mp3')
                .audioBitrate(320)
                .output(fs.createWriteStream(output_dir+"/"+c+".mp3"))
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log("Finished MP3 Convert...");
                })
                .run();
        });
        c++;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed using an example by ytdl-core** [Link](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/convert_to_mp3.js)

Fixed code:

```js
var ytpl = require('ytpl');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var binaries = require('ffmpeg-static');
var sanitize = require('sanitize-filename');
var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

var output_dir = path.join(__dirname+"/dl");

ytpl("PL8n8S4mVUWvprlN2dCAMoIo6h47ZwR_gn", (err, pl) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    for (const i of pl.items) {
        let stream = ytdl(i.id, {
            filter: 'audioonly'
        });

        ffmpeg(stream)
            .audioBitrate(320)
            .save(`${output_dir}/${sanitize(i.title + " (by " + i.author.name + ")")}.mp3`)
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log("Done! Downloaded \""+i.title + " (by " + i.author.name + ")"+"\"");
            });
    }
});
```